# Ubuntu - restarting mysql from command prompt within mysql

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I can restart mysql with

```
sudo restart mysql
```

but can I do this from the mysql command line prompt?

```
mysql >
```

Comment: what happens with: **\! sudo restart mysql** ? It should exec shell commands, but I don't know how it works with **sudo**

Answer (score 1):

You can find all commands here :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html

By the way do you need to restart the client or the server ? cause they're are two different service

Also you can use : mysql> system sudo restart mysql